# How to print or join specific elements of a list (Python)?

Tags: python, list, join

```
list = [8,4,3,2,5]
```

Is there a way to join two elements not using slice

```
print ' '.join(list[0:3]) #would print out the numbers in between
```

What if I want to print just those specific elements?

Comment: So what's wrong with `print list[0]`? or `print list[0], list[3]`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [Python's string formatter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string-formatting):

```
>>> arr = [8,4,3,2,5]
>>> print "{0} {3}".format(*arr)
8 2
```

Also, please don't name your variables after built-in functions/types such as `list`.

Comment: This looks neat, but `print arr[0], arr[3]` is actually shorter and doesn't require the entire `arr` to be copied into an argument tuple. `print '{0[0]} {0[3]}'.format(arr)` offers the flexibility of string formatting while also not requiring the copy.